# iPhone how to validate a string is just a image name or image url in Objective - c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, regex, validation

On my xib I have a `UITextField` and `UIImageView` and a button,

[image]

what actually I want is when user can enter image name e.g. `Default.png` OR a full web `URL` of image and when press that button should check

if text is simple e.g. Default.png then use the local image and
if text is web URL with image then load data from image URL and create a image and then put on UIImageView.

I have checked many question here but did not get exact solution for what I want to achieve.

What I have done: (Which is not working)

```
//  imageViewViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface imageViewViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField * urlInput;
    IBOutlet UIImageView * myImgView;
}

- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;
@end
```

Code from .m file

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender
{
    NSString *url = urlInput.text;
    UIImage *tempImg;

    if([self validateUrl:url]) {
        NSURL *imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSData *imagedata = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:imageurl];
        tempImg = [UIImage imageWithData: imagedata];       
    } else {
        tempImg = [UIImage imageNamed:url];
    }

    if(tempImg == nil){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Image not present!!!" message:@"Image not present!!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        myImgView.image = tempImg;
    }
}

- (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *urlRegEx =
    @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Even after entering correct image URL it is showing me alert "Image not present!!!"

I think there is problem with my URL validation function.

Comment: Just because I type in the url (http://tempuri.org/swinsuit.png) it would pass your validation function.  But it doesn't mean a photo actually exists.

Comment: Yes you are right, I just want to check what user entered, a URL or just image name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for check that its valid URL or not...

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
bool valid = [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:req];
```

Comment: Will this work in different way for image name and image URL?

Comment: no no its return that entered URL is valid or Handle by the URLRequest class or not.. here if its you can use that boll variable valid instead of [self validateUrl:url] code.. :)

Comment: Perfect!! Can You explain me.

Comment: yes why not?? see here NSURLRequest class used for send url request so first here it required NSURL with our url and we convert our string url into NSURL with URLWithString function like above... after in 2nd line we check that its right url or not(means its handle by the NSURLRequest or not with canHandleRequest function.. it give me true or false with its right URL or not.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the

```
+(id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString
```

method of `NSURL`, which returns nil if the string is not URL

"The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. Must be a URL that conforms to RFC 2396. This method parses URLString according to RFCs 1738 and 1808." (c) 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

The code support the string is URL or Not,

```
NSString *incoming_string=@"http://www.gmail.com";
NSString *substring=@"http";
NSRange textRange = [incoming_string rangeOfString:substring];
  if(textRange.location != NSNotFound){
    NSLog(@"This is url image");
}else{
    NSLog(@"This is SYSTEM Image");
}
```

Comment: What if some body enters URL that starts with https:// or www. or any other?  Can you suggest some valid regax for this.

Comment: In ios. valid URL starts with http or https only.Https is also find this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:txtField.text]]];
if(img)
{
// Do something
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to check for a valid url

```
- (BOOL)isValidUrl:(NSString *)urlString{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    return [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working perfectly. Can you please explain me what actually this code is doing as I am new to Objective-c and iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternative to check valid URL :

Method 1:

```
- (BOOL)CheckUrl:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    return [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:request];
}
```

Method 2 :

```
NSString *urlRegEx = @"http(s)?://([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+(/[\\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?";
```

Hope this might solve the problem